# How can I see the hierarchy of objects inside a layer in Krita, so I can move them up and down?

Tags: krita

How can I see the hierarchy of objects inside a layer in Krita?

I need this feature (that I loved in Fireworks) to move up or down some objects.

Answer (score 1):

In Krita, vector layers have a hierarchy of objects within them, but as far as I know, there's no panel where you can see these objects listed if they are all in the one layer. Paint layers (i.e. raster layers) have no such hierarchy within them, graphics in a paint layer are not individually selectable like vector objects on a vector layer.

It's probably better to keep individual objects on separate layers if you want to see them listed separately in the layers panel. If you want to manage these multiple layers easily, you could use layer groups.

However, if you just want to move vector objects up or down inside a layer, it's possible to do that in *Settings > Dockers > Arrange*. With an object selected you can move an object up or down the stack within its layer, using the buttons shown here.

[image]

Comment: When I show this to my boss for no particular reason https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zr2xC.gif

Comment: @Joonas - LOL. Did it work?

Comment: Nah. He doesn't know what Krita is. The other thing is probably a mystery too.